# Nested For Loop in Batch

Tags: loops, batch-file, for-loop, nested

Ive look over many threads and cannot seem to put together a solution to my problem.

What i would like to do is use two lists to create one output.

```
set Client_ID=BJCH,BORG,FGMS,SVIN,JEFF,NWIL
set PartNo=1,2,9,10,12,20

for %%A in (%Client_ID%) do (
    for %%B in (%PartNo%) do (
        echo %%A %%B 

        )
)
```

But the output I get is:

```
BJCH 1
BJCH 2
BJCH 9
BJCH 10
BJCH 12
BJCH 20
BORG 1
BORG 2
BORG 9
BORG 10
BORG 12
BORG 20
FGMS 1
FGMS 2
FGMS 9
etc........
```

What i need is

```
BJCH 1
BORG 2
FGMS 9
SVIN 10
JEFF 12
NWIL 20
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your two lists are *separated ones*: if you nest one `for` into the other one, you are *multiplying* the number of results. There is no way to process *both lists* in the same `for`, unless you convert the lists into two [arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10166386/arrays-linked-lists-and-other-data-structures-in-cmd-exe-batch-script/10167990#10167990) and then process both arrays in the same `for`, that is, process the elements of the two arrays with same index. For example:

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set Client_ID[1]=BJCH
set Client_ID[2]=BORG
etc...

set PartNo[1]=1
set PartNo[2]=2
etc...

for /L %%i in (1,1,6) do echo !Client_ID[%%i]! !PartNo[%%i]!
```

You may also simulate previous processing ("two elements with same index") this way:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set Client_ID=BJCH,BORG,FGMS,SVIN,JEFF,NWIL
set PartNo=1,2,9,10,12,20

set i=0
for %%A in (%Client_ID%) do (
   set /A i+=1, j=0
   for %%B in (%PartNo%) do (
      set /A j+=1
      if !i! equ !j! echo %%A %%B 
   )
)
```

**EDIT**: *Output example added*

```
BJCH 1
BORG 2
FGMS 9
SVIN 10
JEFF 12
NWIL 20
```

Comment: Thanks for the response but i done seem to get any output with your change.

Comment: Ok, that seems like it would work, i will give ti a try. Only thing is i have a list of about 20 client and they may grow is all. Thank you sir.

Comment: Ok i found a flaw in my existing script and found running both your code separately works perfect. Thanks again for the help.